# Server stopping on deploying my war

Tags: glassfish

I am new here.
I am using glassfish server 4.0.
When i am deploying my war,it says classversionexception and deployment fails.
How to fix this? any suggestions would be apprepriated.

Comment: You should add the stacktrace of the exception to the question.